# ajax XHR failed loading: POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, xmlhttprequest

so I am trying to post with ajax, and it just wont go through.

here is my javascript

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
        {
            var o = {};
            var a = this.serializeArray();
            $.each(a, function() {
                if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                    if (!o[this.name].push) {
                        o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                    }
                    o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
                } else {
                    o[this.name] = this.value || '';
                }
            });
            return o;
        };

        $(function() {
            $('#formulario').submit(function() {
                formData = JSON.stringify($('#formulario').serializeObject());
                console.log(formData);
                //return false;

                                    $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "http://localhost/teleinformatica/API/user/validarLogin",
              data: formData,
              success: function(data){console.log(data.msg);},
              error: function(){location.reload();},
              dataType: "json",
              contentType : "application/json"
            });


            });
        });
```

I am not getting an error nor am I getting a success from ajax. But I am getting a chrome console error listed above XHR failed loading: POST

sometimes the post is done correctly, and others i get XHR failed loading: POST

This is the error

```
XHR failed loading: POST 
"http://localhost/teleinformatica/API/user/validarLogin".
   send @ script/jquery.min.js:2
   ajax @ script/jquery.min.js:2
   (anonymous function) @ p2.php:89
   dispatch @ script/jquery.min.js:2
   u @ script/jquery.min.js:2
```

Any help on this matter really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your data must be

Type: PlainObject or String or Array 
& success method must have at least one argument

Type: Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
example :

```
formData = {data1:"yourdata1", data2:1021};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/teleinformatica/API/user/validarLogin",
    data: formData,
    success: function(data){console.log(data);},
   dataType: "json",
   contentType : "application/json"
});
```

Comment: data is as you say, i'm getting it from a form, i'll add the code to the original post, thaks